# What does this error mean in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

error: could not read data from '/Users/Nilay/Desktop/Map Excercise/Map Exercise/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

The Info.plist file is literally right in front of my eyes and it is telling me it doesn't exist, which makes no sense. Please help

Here is my github: https://github.com/nneeranjun/Map-Exercise

Comment: try clean and rebuild

Comment: is the plist added to the project? if it is, maybe delete it and re-add it :? sounds like a strange situation

Comment: Please include the error as reported by Xcode.  You don't even tell us which part of the build is failing, or if it's building but dying at runtime.

Comment: its not even building

Comment: i included the error

Comment: GoogleService-Info.plist file is not in your project. Its showing in red color. So please add this plist file in your project.

Comment: its already part of the project. it isnt showing up red for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Build Settings** > **Packaging**: Correct the `Info.plist File` field

Comment: there was nothing wrong with it; i thought it was supposed to be Map Excercise/Info.plist